# Related posts popup

Tags: plugins, posts

I want to retain visitors on my blog by showing them other posts related to the post they are reading. But it seems they don't see this widget at all. So I have an idea to show this list in a popup (DIV) which appears in the bottom (or any side) of the page after the user scrolls the post for some extent.

Does anybody know the best way to do this?

Comment: By "popup" do you mean another browser window or just a div container appearing ("popping up")?

Comment: Yes, I mean DIV popup

Comment: This doesn't seem like a WordPress-specific question. The answer to your question has been answered many times, I assume, on SO. You'll need some jQuery and CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found exactly what I was looking for: http://wordpress.org/plugins/upprev/